# AUVIO Universal Remote Receiver - does it work on a pc?

Tags: htpc, universal-remote

I found this product for the PS3: http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=10852495

I'm wondering if this receiver will work on a PC using any of the Harmony remotes?  I need to find a universal remote control receiver and this one sounds promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...to counteract the tumbleweed blowing around...

The device gets recognized by my PC (Windows 7 64-bit)...and I used EventGhost to find it and it recognized the device as a PS3 game controller.

I didn't take it further than that because I returned the device...I figured that I would have issues mapping keypad numbers onto game controller mapping...